# adminlte rails sidebar not working properly

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, adminlte

I looked around but couldnt find a problem like this, probably is a stupid one but I couldnt find the answer.

I just installed "adminlte-rails" gem, when I paste the example code for the left sidebar it works but the boxes are not coloring properly , here is the code I'm using and the result :

Example Code :

```
<div class="main-sidebar">
  <!-- Inner sidebar -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <!-- user panel (Optional) -->
    <div class="user-panel">
      <div class="pull-left image">
        <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left info">
        <p>User Name</p>

        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.user-panel -->

    <!-- Search Form (Optional) -->
    <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </form><!-- /.sidebar-form -->

    <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
      <li class="header">HEADER</li>
      <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a><</li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Another Link</span></a></li>
      <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#"><span>Multilevel</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul><!-- /.sidebar-menu -->

  </div><!-- /.sidebar -->
</div><!-- /.main-sidebar -->
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpINm.png)

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L0OG.png)

I tried applying the same classes to the body but no colors appeared.

Thanks!!

Comment: did you added require css to application.css?

Comment: The problem was related with that , I will detail in my own answer, thanks for reading and answering by the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could find the solution and ofcourse was an easy one.

"adminlte-rails" gem works with an old AdminLTE version ( 1.x , actually 2.3 version) so gems sidebar classes were different to classes I was including in  my code I guess. First I tried to manually import a fresh "skins-blue.css" file into the project and colors worked, but functions like 3 level menues didnt work , so I decided to delete the gem and include to my project the CSS and Js files and now works like a charm.

Thanks to @sadaf2605 for answering.

regards